# Does Resharper 4.1 support both Camel Humps and normal selection modes?

Tags: resharper, devtools, camelcasing

I've found the setting for Camel Humps in resharper:

Resharper -> Options -> Editor -> Use CamelHumps

The problem is that I would still like to be able to use the normal selection mode (i.e. the default behaviour for CTRL+Arrow and CTRL+SHIFT+Arrow) as well as the CamelHumps mode.

For example consider this variable:

private int MyVeryLongCamelCaseName;

Now if I want to copy the entire variable then I want the VS default behaviour for CTRL+SHIFT+Left-Arrow which is to select the entire variable if the cursor is on the M.

However if I want to change the name to say MyExtremelyLongCamelCaseName then I would like the CamelHumps behaviour provided by Resharper.

**Is there any way to have both behaviours with different shortcuts?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- disable CamelHumps in Resharper -> Options -> Editor -> Use CamelHumps.
- go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard and

  - bind the keys you want to 'Resharper.HumpNext' and 'ResharperHuntPrev' (I use alt+left / alt+right)
  - and bind keys to 'Resharper.HumpNextExtent' and 'Resharper.HumpPrevExtent' for selection shortkeys. (I had to remove keybindings for shift+alt+left/right from 'Edit.Char[Left/Right]ExtentColumn' first)

Comment: It's in the same place on 5.x.  I couldn't find it to save my life the other day, thanks :)

Comment: Since I use Alt + Left/Right arrow I assigned Alt + Left/Right Windows Key to Resharper.HumpPrev/Next. They're not assigned by default to any visual studio commands :)

Comment: +1. Brilliant! Still works many versions of ReSharper later. BTW, it seems to work well to apply these shortcuts to "Text Editor" only (rather than "Global"). It looks like you can also apply to specific editors (such as XAML or XML), but "Text Editor" is a good choice if you want to be able to use the same cursor shortcuts in every text editor.

Answer (score 2):

I think ctrl+W shotkey will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option for this but as a work around you can use the Extend Selection shortcut which is CTRL+ALT+Right. Not ideal but faster than hitting CTRL+SHIFT+Right multiple times for a symbol that has a lot of camel humps.